# Cookie not updating

Tags: c#, cookies

I am trying to update a cookie value, but it doesn't work - everything I have tried doesn't update the cookie and I always get the initial value of the cookie.

So I have searched and according to MSDN I should be able to update a cookie by doing the following:

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("cookiename");
cookie.Value = cookieValue;
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Set(cookie); // also just tried using .Add again here
```

As this didn't work, I did another search and people on SO said I should be able to do this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["cookiename"].Value = cookieValue;
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["cookiename"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
```

But this didn't work either so I tried deleting the cookie and re-adding it:

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("cookiename");
cookie.Value = cookieValue;
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

I have also tried removing the cookie with the following before re-adding it

```
ResponseCookies.Remove("cookiename");
```

And this also didn't work, so I'm now not sure what else to try.  Does anyone know how to update a cookie with c#?

**Update**

If I step through the code and check `HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["cookiename"].Value` after I have updated it, it shows the new value.  If I then recycle the app pool so that the cookie has to be read from the file again, it shows the original value, so it seems the above code is not updating the physical cookie

Comment: Try removing and then adding cookie back with new value. see if that works. Is it ajax request?

Comment: @MihirSolanki, not an ajax request - otherwise I would have used `$.cookie` as that works better - it actually updates the cookie!

Comment: You cannot directly updating the physical cookie because the cookie is on the user's computer. It's the responsibility of the browser to discard the cookie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can't!**

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx), you have replace the current cookie with a new one with the same name. There is a whole section about this.

> **Modifying and Deleting Cookies**
>
> You cannot directly modify a cookie. Instead, changing a cookie consists of creating a new cookie
> with new values and then sending the cookie to the browser to
> overwrite the old version on the client.

---

**Update**

After writing in the comments, we found the problem here.

You are also not allowed to use a semi-colon in your cookie-value, according to the [specs](https://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html).

> This string is a sequence of characters **excluding semi-colon**, **comma**
> and **white space**. If there is a need to place such data in the name or
> value, some encoding method such as URL style %XX encoding is
> recommended, though no encoding is defined or required.

Comment: I've read that whole section and tried what it has said in that section (as you can see by my attempts in my question)

Comment: @Pete Have you tried to change the Expires Date from the new cookie?

Comment: @Pete Which Browser your are testing in?

Comment: @Pete Or do your `cookieValue` contains a `;`?

Comment: Ah yes, it does contain a semi-colon - is that a problem?

Comment: Yep... this is an illegal character in cookies!

Comment: No way!  Removing the `;` has done the trick, if you add that to your answer I'll accept it.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Finally! :D So much struggle with this little fellow.

Answer (score 0):

I face a similar kind of issues. If fix this by using the following method to set and get the cookies.

```
 public static void SetCookie(string key, string value, TimeSpan expires, bool http = false)
        {
        
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[key] != null)
            {
                
                var cookieOld = new HttpCookie(key);
                cookieOld.Expires = DateTime.Now.Add(expires);
                cookieOld.Value = value;
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookieOld);
            }
            else
            {
                HttpCookie encodedCookie = new HttpCookie(key, value);
                encodedCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.Add(expires);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(encodedCookie);
            }
        }
```

And the following code used to GetCookie

```
 public static string GetCookie(string key)
        {
            string value = string.Empty;
            HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[key];

            if (cookie != null)
            {
                value = cookie.Value;
            }
            return value;
        }
```

The following way to call get and set functions

```
public static string CustomerName
        {
            get { return CookieStore.GetCookie("customername"); }
            set { CookieStore.SetCookie("customername", value.ToString(), TimeSpan.FromHours(24), true); }
        }
```