# Deleting specific key/values from cookie in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I have a shopping cart that adds all shopping cart items to a cookie so when the user goes to his "cart" to check out, the items populate that page...I have that part working, but I have a `POST` request when a user wants to delete an item from the cart that does not seem to delete the item off the cookie.

My cookie string looks like this (for example if there are two items they've added to cart: `1=X Large&2=Small` where the left is the `productId` and the right is the `MerchSize`

Here's my code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RemoveItem(int? ID)
{
    //pull existing cookie and get string value
    string cookie = "";
    if (this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains("CartCookie"))
    {
        cookie = this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["CartCookie"].Value;
    }

    if (cookie != "")
    {
        //convert string cookie into a dictionary
        Dictionary<string, string> keyValuePairs = cookie.Split('&')
        .Select(value => value.Split('='))
        .ToDictionary(pair => pair[0], pair => pair[1]);

        //delete the existing cookie if it exists at all
        if (this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains("CartCookie"))
        {
            HttpCookie deleteCookie = this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["CartCookie"];
            deleteCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
            this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(deleteCookie);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("cookie deleted");
        }

        // remove a specific key/value pair from the dictionary
        if (keyValuePairs.Remove(ID.Value.ToString()))
        {

            HttpCookie updatedCookie = Request.Cookies["CartCookie"];
            if (updatedCookie == null)
            {
                // no cookie found, create it
                updatedCookie = new HttpCookie("CartCookie");

                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in keyValuePairs)
                {
                    updatedCookie.Values[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // update the cookie values
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in keyValuePairs)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
                    updatedCookie.Values[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value;
                }
            }

            // update the expiration timestamp
            updatedCookie.Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(30);

            // overwrite the cookie
            Response.Cookies.Add(updatedCookie);

            //print the value of the new cookie
            string newcookie = "";
            if (this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains("CartCookie"))
            {
                newcookie = this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["CartCookie"].Value;
            }
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(newcookie);

        }
        else
        {
            // dictionary doesn't contain above key
        }  
}

    return Json(true);

}
```

As you can see, I am printing the output at different lines, here is what I see in my console:

```
cookie deleted //confirms that the cookie delete function runs
Key = 1, Value = X Large //shows that only one item is in the NEW dictionary
1=X Large&2=Small //shows that the new cookie still has both items
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cookie not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35912581/cookie-not-updating).

Comment: @RMH kind of! However, I understand that you need to completely remove and re-add new cookie. However, after deleting the cookie (or I think I am) I still see the same info in the cookie at the very end

Comment: @mjwills nothing changes, which obviously leads me to believe my delete block doesn't work. I cannot seem to track why though..

Comment: @mjwills I believe it's `request` as I need the updated cookie that was changed from the browser. However, I tried with `response` and that did not change my output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems my earlier comment on the possible duplicate was incorrect. On further inspection and I noted that, when the cookie already exists, the values are updated, however the values that need to be removed are not actually being removed from the cookie itself.

---

So the problem is in the following piece of code:

```
HttpCookie updatedCookie = Request.Cookies["CartCookie"];
if (updatedCookie == null)
{
    // [omitted]
}
else
{
    // update the cookie values
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in keyValuePairs)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
        updatedCookie.Values[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value;
    }
}
```

When the cookie already exist, its taken and *only* the values that are in the `keyValuePairs` dictionary are updated. In earlier statements you've already removed a value from the dictionary, however the dictionary is not tied to the cookie, meaning that your removed key still exists within the cookie.

You'll need to ensure that the cookie value is either empty:

```
// Clear the cookie value entirely
cookie.Value = null;
```

or even better, remove a specific key:

```
// Remove a specific key from the cookie value
cookie.Values.Remove(ID.Value.ToString());
```

The latter seems preferable to me, as it will not require you to parse the values into a dictionary and update them.

---

As a sidenote, you are not required to delete a cookie if you want to update it's value. Just send back the updated cookie with its new properties (value,  time etc.) and the existing cookie on the client will be updated.

Comment: excellent, thanks for checking back up on this question. You are correct I was missing the `null` value on the cookie while deleting. This fixed it :)